# Exp:resso Store v3 won't update to 3.0.1

Tags: expresso-store, add-on, update

I'm in the process of moving my clients site from Expression Engine 2 to the latest build of Expression Engine 3. This obviously includes updating all the Add ons.

I have successfully installed Exp:resso Store 3.0.0, but now wish to install the 3.0.1 update. All the files are on the server, but when clicking the 'update to 3.0.1' button on the add on list, or visiting the Store Dashboard the updates don't run and no errors are shown.

I'm not sure if this is a specific Store issue, or if this can be a known issue with updating Add-ons. Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: If in Add-Ons the Version column shows 3.0.1, then it should be installed even if the "update to 3.0.1" is still showing. (Thinking it's a display fix that may show up on the next version.)

Comment: Yeah - I've just head back from their support. They say it is a display issue - so nothing to worry about. *sigh* thats 3 hours of trying to fix it I'll never get back :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment though Romans!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've heard back from Exp:resso support. The addon is updating even though the button isn't showing so. It seems it is just a display issue which will be resolved in the next build.

Thanks to Romans-8--31-39 for the comments suggesting as much above.